# How to find cause of EC2 micro instance regular read/write surge?

Tags: amazon-ec2, top

Every day without fail, sometime between 06:20 and 07:00 UTC, I get two email alerts from EC2 warning me that my "High VolumeWriteBytes" and "High VolumeReadBytes" have exceeded my set threshold.  I get a massive spike of 2,000,000 bytes for a few minutes, then it returns to almost zero for the rest of the day.

I am running just a very simple wordpress website on the server which gets very few visitors anyway and none at that time of the day apart from spiders. When I look in the apache log, there is nothing unusual at that time.

How can I go about tracking down the cause of this problem?

I am thinking to output the "top" command to a file during that period, but I am not sure how to write the cron script, and not sure if the top command will reveal anything anyway?

Comment: Do you have reporting like webalizer or similar? Those will write periodically. Also check your cron jobs for the time period to see if something runs during then.

Comment: No reporting programs.  I have 13 files in my /etc/cron.daily though.  I have looked in /etc/crontab and found this:  # m h dom mon dow user  command
25 6    * * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily )
So I think this suggests one of the crons is causing the problem, but the problem now is how to find which one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run `atop` as a daemon, logging every minute:

```
/usr/bin/atop -a -w /var/log/atop.log 60
```

Then use `atop -r` the next day to step through the logs, sorting by disk usage to see which process is responsible for the I/O surge.

Comment: Thank you.  I have run that command and will check the result tomorrow.  What command do I type to end the daemon?

Comment: You don't say which distro you're using, but the Debian/Ubuntu package `atop` will start the daemon automatically (you'll have to edit `/etc/init.d/atop` to change the recording interval if you want to do that).  If you do have an init script, you can just `/etc/init.d/atop stop`.  If not, just kill the process.  My advice would be to leave it running always -- the data can be invaluable.

Comment: Awesome.  I have changed the recording interval to 120 secs and restarted it, will check the result tomorrow.

Comment: OK I have checked the result and found that cron is the culprit:   PID        RDDSK         WRDSK        WCANCL         DSK       CMD         1/5
  722        3420K            4K            0K         98%       cron       But, this is vague.  I have 13 items in my daily cron, so how do I go aout narrowing down which one is the problem?